# Ask user for key:value pair in Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, data-structures

I want to ask the user for multiple key value pairs and store these so I can use them later. I have tried a couple of things:

`columnCombo = {(x for x in input("Enter the Column Name: ")) : (y for y in input("\nEnter the Column Type: "))}`

`columnCombo = [(x for x in input("Enter the Column Name: ")),(y for y in input("\nEnter the Column Type: "))]`

When I print these out I get:

`[<generator object <genexpr> at 0x1019452d0>, <generator object <genexpr> at 0x101945318>]`

Really what I want is to ask for the user for the name of a column and then the type of data that will be contained within that column. Ideally I'd be able to pull out the name (string) and associated (type)

Comment: Do want to do this only one time or until the user indicates they are done?

Comment: Loop until the user enters a blank value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store these objects in a tuple, like so:

```
done = False;
key_value_pairs = []
while not done:
    col_name = input("Enter the Column Name: ")
    if col_name == "":
         done = True
    col_type = input("Enter the Column Type: ")
    if col_type == "":
        done = True

    key_value_pairs.append((col_name, col_type))
```

And then as soon as you finish, you could iterate through your entries like so:

```
for key_value_pair in key_value_pairs:
    key = key_value_pair[0]
    value = key_value_pair[1]
```

Comment: This is great, exactly what I was looking to do. Do you know why my one liner doesn't work? I'm learning data structures and wanted to condense it down as much as possible into a dictionary or tuple in one line and thought I was actually onto something.

Comment: @AmericanKryptonite One sec - lemme check a little more.

Comment: @AmericanKryptonite First point - those lines are way too long. Python style is really into the idea of only having 80 characters of code per line, and it sorta defeats the purpose of one-lining something if everyone has to change their editor width just to read it.

Secondly, I'm not sure there's a way to combine input() and comprehensions. I can tell you that the reason you're getting the generator reference when you print it out is that (a for a in b) is a generator comprehension, which is a function that lazily iterates each item as needed, rather than loading the entire list.

Answer (score 1):

```
column = {}
print "when done press ctrl+c" 
while True:
    try:
        col_name = input("Enter the Column Name: ")
        col_type = input("Enter the column type: ")
        column[col_name] = col_type
    except KeyboardInterrupt:break
```

In the above code it will prompt for input unitl user press keyboard interrupt

loopin over the `column` dictionary

```
for key in column.keys():
    col_name = key
    col_type = column[key]
```

Comment: I want to store them in a data structure so I can refer to them all at once in another loop later on.

Comment: I edited the code,now its is stored in column dictionary as column name as `key` and column type as `value`

Comment: This will not run in python 3.x: raw_input does not exist anymore. It's input().